# Traversing a Javascript Linked list skips the last item

Tags: javascript, linked-list

```
var someList = {
                   data : 1,
                   next : {
                              data : 2,
                                  next : {
                                             data : 3,
                                             next : {
                                                        data : 4,
                                                        next : null
                                                    }
                                         }
                          }
               };

var ar = []; 

function reversePrint( LList )
{
    var c = null;
    c = LList;

    while ( c.next != null )
    {
        ar.unshift( c.data );
        c = c.next;
    }

    console.log( ar );
}
```

This routine outputs data in array in reverse order.

The problem is : the loop doesn't get `data : 4`.

How do I rewrite it to output all of the data?

Comment: I think you want a do {} while loop, since presumably if next is null, you want it to still retreive the value before aborting the loop?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
for (var c = LList; c; c = c.next) {
    // do something with c.data
}
```

Comment: +1 Note that you'll need to do the unshift in this loop. Kudos for short and sweet though

Answer (score 2):

Think about what would happen if you only had one element. You would still want to add the data to the array right? That means you want to execute the loop body *at least once*. In this case you should a [`do...while` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/do...while):

```
function reversePrint(c){
    var ar = [];
    do {
        ar.unshift(c.data);
    } while (c = c.next);
    console.log(ar) // print ;)
    return ar;
}
```

Comment: +1, this is the nicest most concise, but note, it's not "printing"

Comment: @altCognito: To be fair, the OP's function is also not "printing" ;)

Comment: lol, very true, very true, I actually wanted to suggest that returning the reverse array seems more like the canonical "reverse" implementation. (as in, this is a good thing) Either way, it's a bit of a homework problem.

Comment: Yknow, the comment again the question got me thinking though -- shouldn't this be while (c) {ar.unshift(c.data); c=c.next} - otherwise, you'll get a null exception

Answer (score 2):

I'll throw another one in.

```
function reverse(ll) {
  var ar = [];
  while (ll) {
    ar.unshift(ll.data);
    ll = ll.next;
  }
  return ar; 
}

var newList = reverse(someList);
for(var x=0;x<newList.length;x++) {
  console.log(newList[x]);
}
```

OR

Recursively, very, very small. But heavy on the stack, which I am not fond of:

```
function reversePrint(ll) {
  if (ll.next) reversePrint(ll.next);
  console.log(ll.data);
}

reversePrint(someArray);
```

See them at work: http://jsbin.com/ataji4

Comment: but how does recursion work here exactly?? Does console.log get executed before invoking reversePrint(ll.next) next time?? I thought console.log never got a chance to run, because reversePrint constantly calls itself..

Answer (score 1):

Actually I`ve implemented one example for linked lists in javascript which is more displayable of what should llist be:

```
function Link(k, d) {
    this.obj = {
        'key': k,
        'data' : d,
        'next' : null 
        };
    return this.obj;
}
function List() {
    this.firstLink = new Link();
    this.insertFirst = function(key, data) {
        this.newLink = new Link(key, data);
        this.newLink.next = this.firstLink;
        this.firstLink = this.newLink;
        }
    this.getFirst = function() {
        return this.firstLink;
        }
    this.removeFirst=function() {
        var temp = this.firstLink;
        this.firstLink = this.firstLink.next;
        delete temp;
        }
    this.displayList=function() {
        this.current = this.firstLink;
        while ( this.current != null ) {
            console.log(this.current);
            this.current = this.current.next;
            }
        }

    }
var lst = new List();
lst.insertFirst(22, 'ilian');
lst.insertFirst(55, 'xoxo');
lst.insertFirst(77, 'fefe');

lst.displayList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var ar = []; 

function reversePrint(LList){
  var c = null;
  c = LList;
  while (c.next != null) {
    ar.unshift(c.data);
    c = c.next;
  }
  ar.unshift(c.data); //gets that last element
  c=c.next; //c now equals null

  console.log(ar);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple implementation of `LinkedList` along with traversal can be done like this in JavaScript:

```js
(function(){
 'use strict';
 var LinkedList = function(){
  this.head = null;
 }
 
 LinkedList.prototype.appendToTail = function(data){
  var node = {
   "data":data,
   "next":null
  };
  
  if(this.head == null){
   this.head = node;
  }else{
   var current = this.head;
   while( current.next != null){
    current = current.next;
   }
   current.next = node;
  }
 }
  
  LinkedList.prototype.traverseList = function(){
      var current = this.head;
      while(current != null){
          console.log(current.data);
          current = current.next;
      }
  
  }
 
  var linkedList = new LinkedList();
  linkedList.appendToTail(20);
  linkedList.appendToTail(30);
  linkedList.appendToTail(40);
     
  linkedList.traverseList();
 
})()
```